# How to validate XML against multiple XSD files?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need to validate multiple *XML* files against given *XSD* files. The problem is that *XSD* is made out of two files. They are nested, though I know which one is the first ("parent" of others). In the *XML* file I use namespaces to define in which *XSD* the childnode is defined `(<CBIBdySDDReq xmlns="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBdySDDReq.00.00.06" xmlns:msg="urn:CBI:xsd:CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.00.06">`).
I am using *XMLTools* plugin for *Notepad++* for the other tests, but it is not able to find and validate against these *XSD* files, cause I can only give one *XSD* to validate against as parameter.

**Is there a tool that is able to test my generated *XML* files against more than one *XSD* files?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should consider yourself lucky that you didn't get heavily downvoted... if only because tools that are to do things (recommendations) are outside the scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/about)...

Nonetheless, if this is about how to achieve what you need using the tool that you're already using... and for which I've seen lots of issues reported on SO... then one approach which would work anytime someone has the limitation of being able to provide a single XSD file... is to create such an XSD file which underneath would import all the other XSD files that you need referenced.

This is an example of a stub XSD that would work in your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="(a)" schemaLocation="(b)"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

where:

(a) is the value you see in the targetNamespace attribute of the xsd:schema you wish referenced; if there's no targetNamespace, then remove the namespace attribute (and add a targetNamespace containing some dummy value to the stub XSD)

(b) the location of the file containing the XSD you want to reference. Start by using the full path here; as you learn more about XSD or your tool, you may reach the conclusion that it is better, if supported by your tool, to provide the relative URI, that is between the location of your "stub" XSD (it really is an "aggregator") and the other referenced XSD. Relative URIs are friendlier in terms of moving your stuff around (as a whole unit, as in zipping all your files and send to someone else). An example... if the files are in the same folder, you simply have to put here the name of the file.

Add one xsd:import line for each of the XSDs that are not "reachable" through all the other XSDs, or that your tool seems to complain about as non-reachable.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. I am new to SO so i did not know that it does not belong here. I thought that if the tool helps me by developing the Export code for the XML File which is the case it is okay to post it here. The other XML-XSD related questions on SO i have seen so far were about implementing an own Validation System. Thanks for the fast and clear answer (:

Comment: @Springrbua, no worries; recommending tools is bound to yield polemics, at least in most cases... The best tool is the one that one knows and does what one needs... and given the format and focus of SO...

Comment: I have seen that questions on SO should not be opinion based and i ll try to think about it next time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out there is another method to achieve this. However, I should first state that I believe Notepad++'s schema validation tool is... buggy, and so this method I'm providing won't work with Notepad++'s XMLTools plugin. Normally, you should be able to declare multiple namespaces and their corresponding schema files in the XML file's root element, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns="https://www.A.org"
xmlns:r="https://www.B.org"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.A.org A.xsd https://www.B.org B.xsd" >
```

The above example is similar to the one provided on page 454 of O'Reilly's XML In a Nutshell.

In such a case, when you run validation in Notepad++, you don't have to select the target XSD file for validation because Notepad++ detects your schemaLocation declaration and runs the validation using that. However, it seems that Notepad++ will only check the last declared schema file in the schemaLocation attribute. So in my example, Notepad++ will validate your XML file only against B.xsd and inevitably throw errors. The solution is the one Petru mentions: to import A.xsd into B.xsd via the "import" declaration.

If you are using a more robust XML tool, you might not run into this problem. For example, OxygenXML handles this just fine, as long as you let it detect the XSD files on its own and not force it to validate against a specific XSD.